# Getting “Assign Return Value to New Variables” warning and output is memory address

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am just starting my second semester of CS and the programming language we are using is c++, I am a newbie, of course. I am in the process of writing a program that records the temperatures per month (both high and lows) into a two-Dimensional array. I have some experience before with programming, mainly javascript and python, but nothing out of this world. The programs compiles and runs successfully, but I am not getting the desired results. First of all, here's my code in its entirety (thusfar)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

const int MONTHS = 12;
const int TEMPS = 2;

void getData(); 
void averageHigh(double arr1[][TEMPS]); 

int main()
{

    cout << "This program outputs average high and low temperature for a year in Puerto Rico:\n\n";

    getData();

    return 0;
}

void getData()
{
    ifstream tempsHigh_Low;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double temps[MONTHS][TEMPS];
    tempsHigh_Low.open("tempsHigh_Low.txt");
    if (tempsHigh_Low.is_open())
    {
        for (i; i < MONTHS; i++)
        {
            for (j; j < TEMPS; j++)
            {
                tempsHigh_Low >> temps[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    averageHigh(temps);
}

void averageHigh(double arr1[][TEMPS])
{
    double tempsAvgHigh[MONTHS][TEMPS];
    double sumElements = 0;
    double numElements = MONTHS;
    double averageHighTemp;
    int v = 0, k = 0;
    for (v; v < MONTHS; v++)
    {
        for (k; k < TEMPS; k++)
        {
            sumElements = sumElements + tempsAvgHigh[v][k];
        }
    }
    cout << sumElements << endl; //right here, it prints out memory loc and

//and issues out warning...this is a test to find out whether i can
//proceed to take the arithmetic mean of the first column of the array
//averageHigh

}
```

I'd like to add that this is my first time using this website, I apologize for any mistakes beforehand! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That line does not print a memory address.

Comment: Threw the code into an editor to indent it a bit better and the compiler is screaming at you to listen. Do not ignore the warnings. Warnings mean that your code is syntactically correct and compiles, but the logic looks wonky. The compiler is the first line of defense against bugs, so take full advantage of what it tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the warnings I see when I compile this:

```
 In function 'void getData()':
29:15: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
31:19: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 In function 'void averageHigh(double (*)[2])':
47:11: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
49:15: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
44:12: warning: unused variable 'numElements' [-Wunused-variable]
45:12: warning: unused variable 'averageHighTemp' [-Wunused-variable]
51:58: warning: 'tempsAvgHigh[0][0]' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
51:58: warning: 'tempsAvgHigh[0][1]' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 At global scope:
40:37: warning: unused parameter 'arr1' [-Wunused-parameter]
```

Seems that your for loops are not doing what you expect them to do (or they are, but not with the data you think...)

Perhaps trying:

```
    for (int i=0; i < MONTHS; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < TEMPS; j++)
        {
            tempsHigh_Low >> temps[i][j];
        }
    }
```

and

```
for (int v=0; v < MONTHS; v++)
{
    for (int k=0; k < TEMPS; k++)
    {
        sumElements = sumElements + tempsAvgHigh[v][k];
    }
}
```

may help with some of your warnings.  It sure helps with keeping counter variable into a scope where they won't do harm elsewhere on accident.  Notice that you will need to remove the i,j,v,k declarations higher up in your code as we are now declaring them inline within the for loop.

Also notice that you pass in `arr1` to your average function, but don't use it at all, instead reading from uninitialized stack memory from `tempAvgHig`.  Perhaps you meant to use `arr1` in your loop instead?

This is a start for you.  Welcome to coding.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, I will get on this as soon as i can, i'll return with updates. My sole hobby has mathematics for the part three or more years, and i can tell you, coding is on a whole other level. So mucho so it's worrying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, just as was pointed, I fixed what needed to be fixed and came up with this. This is for an assignment, Ideally what i would've liked is to make a random number generator to output the numbers onto the text file, but I'm short on time.

```
 //Sebastian R. Papanikolaou


#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

const int MONTHS = 12;
const int TEMPS = 2;


void getData(); //getData() function prototype
void averageHigh(double arr1[][TEMPS]);//averageHigh() function prototype
void averageLow(double arr2[][TEMPS]); //averageLow() function prototype
void indexHighTemp(double arr3[][TEMPS]); //indexHighTemp() function prototype
void indexLowTemp(double arr4[][TEMPS]);//indexLowTemp() function prototype

int main() {

    cout << "This program takes in data from a text file (.txt ) and\n"
            "computes the average high and low temperature for the island\n"
            "of Puerto Rico, also it calculates the index highest and lowest\n"
            "temperatures on the island as well\n\n";

    getData();

    return 0;
}
void getData() //gathers input from the text file 'tempsHigh_Low.txt'
               //and stores it into the 2D array 'temps'

{
    ifstream tempsHigh_Low;
    double temps[MONTHS][TEMPS];

    tempsHigh_Low.open("tempsHigh_Low.txt");

    if(tempsHigh_Low.is_open()) {

        for(int i = 0; i < MONTHS; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < TEMPS; j++){
                tempsHigh_Low >> temps[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    averageHigh(temps);//function call to averageHigh() with 'temps' as the parameter    
}

void averageHigh(double arr1[][TEMPS])//calculates the average of the first column in the arr1
{ 

    double sumElements = 0;
    double numElements = MONTHS;
    double averageHighTemp;

    for(int v = 0; v < MONTHS; v++)
    {
        sumElements = sumElements + arr1[v][0];
    }
    averageHighTemp = sumElements/MONTHS;

    cout << "The average high temperature in Puerto Rico is " 
            << averageHighTemp<< "F" << endl << endl;
    averageLow(arr1);//arr1 is sent to the function averageLow()
}

void averageLow(double arr2[][TEMPS])//averageLow() takes in the data from averageLow() and calculates the average the second column of arr2
//arr2 in reality is still 'temps' from getData()
{
    double sumElements = 0;   
    double numElementes = MONTHS;
    double averageLowTemp;

    for(int n = 0; n < MONTHS; n++)
    {
        sumElements = sumElements + arr2[n][1];
    }
    averageLowTemp = sumElements/MONTHS;

    cout << "The average low temperature in Puerto Rico is "
         << averageLowTemp<< "F" << endl << endl;
    indexHighTemp(arr2);//arr2 is sento to indexHighTemp()
}

void indexHighTemp(double arr3[][TEMPS])//calculates the highest value in the first column of arr3
{
    int largestHighTemp;

    for(int l = 0; l < TEMPS; l++)
    {
        largestHighTemp = arr3[0][l];

        for(int e = 0; e < MONTHS; e++)
        {
            if(arr3[e][0] > largestHighTemp)
                largestHighTemp = arr3[e][0];
        }
    }
    cout << "The highest temperature that Puerto Rico reaches is "
            << largestHighTemp << "F" << endl << endl;
    indexLowTemp(arr3);//arr3 is sent to indexLowTemp()
}

void indexLowTemp(double arr4[][TEMPS])//calculates the lowest value in the second column of arr4
{
    int lowestLowTemp;

    for(int a = 0; a < TEMPS;a++)
    {
        lowestLowTemp = arr4[0][a];
        for(int b = 0; b < TEMPS; b++)
        {
            if(arr4[b][1] < lowestLowTemp)
            {
                lowestLowTemp = arr4[b][1];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The lowest temperature that Puerto Rico reaches is "
            << lowestLowTemp << "F" << endl << endl;
}
```

The list of inputs is as follows:

```
83 70
84 70
85 71
86 73
87 74
89 76
88 76
89 76
88 76
86 75
86 74
84 72
```